# Vuforia recognition of hand painted marker

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I have blank sheet and I want to do AR model to this sheet. I have idea do it with painted marker. For example: cross, square or something easy marker which you can paint to sheet. So how can i do it??? I use unity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you want a simple marker so some simple options are:

1. **ARToolkit Simple markers** like Hiro KanZI marker (it's an open source and *completely* free AR Library):

http://artoolkit.org/documentation/doku.php?id=3_Marker_Training:marker_multi

2. **Using [Vuforia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vuforia_Augmented_Reality_SDK), you can try "Frame Marker"**. Vuforia provides more than 500 simple designs. You can paint it or stick it on your sheet:

https://developer.vuforia.com/library/articles/Training/Frame-Markers-Guide

**FYI:** Vuforia and Artoolkit for both Unity packages are available for free. You just have to import it into your Unity project.

Answer (score 0):

I am writing from memory, so it might not be entirely correct.

- Decide what marker you want to use.
- Draw it on paper. Note, however, that the Vuforia SDK identifies points of interest in a target image (most often that is corners), so the more detailed a photo, the more points of interest, which is why their samples use high resolution images of e.g. lots of little stones. Drawing something like a square, cross, or some other simplistic marker, does not work very well.
- Take a photo of it and transfer it to your computer.
- Download Vuforia's Augmented Reality [SDK for Unity](https://developer.vuforia.com/downloads/sdk).
- Register on the Vuforia website and add your photo as an [Image Target](https://developer.vuforia.com/target-manager). Then save/download the database unity package they create for you from your image.
- Also get [a licence key](https://developer.vuforia.com/license-manager).
- In a blank Unity scene, import the SDK.
- Add an AR camera prefab.
- Add an image target prefab.
- Import the downloaded database package (containing your uploaded image).
- On the image target inspector, change the behaviour to use your image as the image target.
- On the AR camera inspector, add your licence key, and specify the image target database.
- Create or import some 3D model / primitive. Make it a child of the image target, and position it to sit on top of the image target.
- Make sure the AR camera is looking at the image target.
- Build the project and run the project, that's about it.

There should be many tutorials online, just google for something like *vuforia augmented reality tutorial*

Comment: You can actually use the UserDefined target prefab which allows to create dynamic markers.

Comment: I tried with simple square. But it is can't recognise my painted square. So i want to use sheet as image for recognition